# Looping through a 2d Array in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I want to loop through a 2D array in F#. The error I am getting is "The type 'obj' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq <*>, IEnumerable<*> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method"

This is how I tried to do it

```
//creates a 3x3 array with values 0   
let g = Array2D.create<int> 3 3 0

for i in g do
    for j in i do
        printf "%d\t" j
    printfn "\n"
printfn "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for r = 0 to Array2D.length1 g - 1 do
    for c = 0 to Array2D.length2 g - 1 do
        printfn "%A " g[r, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a 2D array, but you're iterating through it as though it was a jagged array (i.e. an array of arrays). If you want a 2D array, use the iteration code from the other answer, but if you want to use a jagged array instead, do this:

```ml
//creates a 3x3 jagged array with values 0   
let g =
    Array.init 3 (fun _ ->
        Array.zeroCreate 3)

for i in g do
    for j in i do
        printf "%d\t" j
    printfn "\n"
printfn "\n"
```

Output is:

```
0   
0   
0   

0   
0   
0   

0   
0   
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iter` and `iteri` functions in the `Array2D` module.

```
g |> Array2D.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d" x)

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Note that `iteri` provides two indices.

```
g |> Array2D.iteri (fun i j x -> printfn "[%d,%d] = %d" i j x)

[0,0] = 0
[0,1] = 0
[0,2] = 0
[1,0] = 0
[1,1] = 0
[1,2] = 0
[2,0] = 0
[2,1] = 0
[2,2] = 0
```